# What does operator ":" inside a struct mean in C?

Tags: c, struct, operators

I'm working with a piece of code and I come across with something similar to this:

```
struct {
  int a : 1;
  int b : 1;
};
```

I don't know what is the function of `: 1` here. For your interest, that struct is inside a `union` which in turn is inside a `typedef struct`.

Thanks,

Comment: The : is not an operator here. It's simply a colon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is used to assign value to a `bit`. You can read about bitfields [here](http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/chapter6/bitfields.html).